# Non numeric for x-axis in scatter chart in CHART.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, chart.js

I am trying to generate a scatter chart using chartjs. In my scatter chart i want the x-axis scale label to be a string. But if i try the below code i get numbers in my x-axis label scale

```
datasets: [{
        label: 'Scatter Dataset',
        data: [{
            x: "a",
            y: 0
        }, {
            x: "b",
            y: 3
        }, {
            x: "",
            y: 5
        }]
    }]
```

[image]

How to set my x-axis scale as string values and make the graph work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe what you are asking is achievable with scatter chart. [Documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html) says it only accepts data in a point format. Hence your data definition is even incorrect. You can use line chart and give data in an array format (only y-axis values) and provide `labels` property as array of strings you wish to display as x-axis labels. See the [starting example](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/) for an illustration.

Comment: Thanks for clarrification

Comment: Please see Al Martins answer below.

Answer (score 12):

It is achievable, it is on the documentation. As part of axis definition:

let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: ...
data: ...
options: {
scales: {
xAxes: [{
type: 'category',
labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June']
}]
}
}
});

on: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html

Comment: This needs to be the excepted answer.

Comment: @AndrewHardiman it has been more than 3 years since the answer at that time; the API has improved since that time.

Comment: setting type to category worked for me. Thanks!